# How add Cucumber tests to a pre-existing Gradle project (Java)?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber

I currently have a large gradle project (using Java and IntelliJ) into which I would like to add Cucumber tests. I've taken some basic steps outlined by this link:

http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2014/08/24/cucumberjvm-hello-world-with-gradle

such as adding dependency and repository settings to my build.gradle file like so:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4'
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
}
```

However, I am not sure how to proceed from here. Is there a certain location where I should be creating my Cucumber tests??

Comment: The answers you're looking for can be found here http://docs.cucumber.io/guides/10-minute-tutorial/
you need to define your feature files under the resources subtree and your steps at the same location as normal junit tests - the tests subtree

Comment: Please note you are using quite an old blog. The link provided to the docs should be up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boaz's answer above seems to work. Thanks!

> define your feature files under the resources subtree and your steps at the same location as normal junit tests - the tests subtree